# How can I retrieve a class from a method reference in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, reflection, introspection

I would like to do this:

```
function call(method) {
    const object = // Retrieve the class that declares the method and then construct an instance dynamically.
    method.call(object) // So 'this' is bound to the instance.
}

call(MyClass.prototype.myMethod)
call(AnOtherClass.prototype.anOtherMethod)
```

My goal is to create the instance from a dependency container. That's why the method has to be bound to an instance that will have all the dependencies required by the class.

Comment: Pass in the object as well?

Comment: Unlike other languages that have `class` systems, in JavaScript there is no permanent relationship between methods and the classes in which they're declared.

Comment: Yeah, I'll pass the class object along with the method as mentioned by @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this automatically without some restructuring. If it were me, I'd pass the class as an argument:

```
function call(theClass, method) {
  const instance = new theClass();
  method.call(instance);
}
```

```
call(MyClass, MyClass.prototype.myMethod)
call(AnOtherClass, AnOtherClass.prototype.anOtherMethod)
```

or, you could pass just the prototype method names for the second argument:

```
function call(theClass, method) {
  const instance = new theClass();
  instance[method]();
}
```

```
call(MyClass, 'myMethod')
call(AnOtherClass, 'anOtherMethod')
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I planned to do. I just have a typing problem with TS. How could I enforce the method to be part of the class statically? This might be an independent question though

Comment: Note the potential restriction: Not all constructors will work properly when supplied no parameters.  This is fundamental, I'm fairly certain.  There can be *no* entirely universal technique that will work here.  But it might not affect the OP's needs.